# How to move recurring contribution when changed Payment processor?

Tags: payment-processor, recurring-contributions

We are moving from paypal to another processor. But there’s lots of recurring contributions that are already setup with paypal. What is the best practice when changing payment processors? Thanks

Comment: I just went through this! I'd be happy to chat. Paypal exported our card data and left the "amount" field off the export :X

Comment: Thanks! I have invited you in chat. Are you free now?